# Выводиться ошибка missing a QuerySet

Tags: python, django

Возникла ошибка при изучении книги "Практика создания веб-сайтов на Python" от Владимира Дронова

Ошибку показывает в views.py ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['rubrics'] = Rubric.objects.all()
        return context

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .forms import BbForm
from .models import Bb
from .models import Rubric

class BbCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/create.html'
    from_class = BbForm
    success_url = '/main/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['rubrics'] = Rubric.objects.all()
        return context

def by_rubric(request,rubric_id):
    bbs = Bb.objects.filter(rubric = rubric_id)
    rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
    current_rubric = Rubric.objects.get(pk = rubric_id)
    context={'bbs':bbs,'rubrics':rubrics,'current_rubric':current_rubric}
    return render(request,'bboard/by_rubric.html',context)

def index(request):
    bbs = Bb.objects.all()
    rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
    context = {'bbs':bbs,'rubrics':rubrics}
    return render(request, 'bboard/index.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import index,by_rubric
from .views import BbCreateView
urlpatterns = [
    path('add/',BbCreateView.as_view(),name = 'add'),
    path('<int:rubric_id>/', by_rubric, name = 'by_rubric'),
    path('',index, name = 'index')
]
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Bb

class BbForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bb
        fields = ('title','content','price','rubric')
```

create.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Add Ads - Ads</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Ads</h1>
    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Main</a>
        <a href="{% url 'add' %}">Add</a>
        {% for rubric in rubrics %}
        <a href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric.pk %}">{{ rubric.name }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class BbCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/create.html'
    form_class = BbForm #неправильно на писал (было from_class)
    success_url = '/main/'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['rubrics'] = Rubric.objects.all()
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class BbCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/create.html'
    from_class = BbForm
    success_url = '/main/'
    model = Bb #добавьте вашу модель 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['rubrics'] = Rubric.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: @walkie изменил ответ

Comment: Я сделал это в forms.py, сейчас сделал как вы посоветовали и это не помогло